# how to give multiple classes a style with js

Tags: javascript

```js
//  sticty menu
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var header = document.querySelector("header");
    header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
});

// heder color
const headerScroll = document.querySelector(".header");
const allMenuItem = document.querySelectorAll(".onscroll");


window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 0) {
        headerScroll.classList.add('head-change');
        allMenuItem.forEach(v => {
            v.classList.add('menu-change');
        });
    } else {
        headerScroll.classList.remove('head-change');
        v.classList.remove('menu-change');

    };

});
```

```css
 .head-change {
    background-color: white;
}

.menu-change {
    color: black:
}
/* ==============   ================== */

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header.sticky .navigation {
    line-height: 60px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transition-property: line-height;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
     transition: 0.6s;
}

.header:hover {
    background-color: white;
}

.head-change {
    background-color: white;
}

.menu-change {
    color: black;
}

header .navigation {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 75px;
}

header .navigation .menu {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 }

 

.menu>li a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.header:hover .menu>li a {
    color: var(--black);
}

.sub-menu>li a {
    color: var(--black);
    font-size: 1em;
}

.menu-item>a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 25px 0;
    margin: 18px;
    transform: 0.5s;
}

.menu-item>a:hover {
    color: #469dff;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu .header-icon {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 15px;
}
 

.menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
}

.sub-item {
    position: relative;
    padding: 7px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -30px 5px -30px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}

.sub-item a {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

.sub-item:hover {
    background: #f4f6F7FF;
    ;
}

.sub-item:last-child:hover {
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}

 
 

.slider {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 13vh 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #343134;
    background-image: url(../assets/images/mr.webp);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.slider .slider-head {
    height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    line-height: 0;
}

.slider-head .Be {
    font-size: 7em;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.slider-head:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 7em;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.slider-head .h-header {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 0;
}



.slider-head .theme-version {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .35em .65em;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
<header id="head">
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#">logo</a>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <!-- menu-icon -->

            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a class="onscroll" href="#">item</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a class="sub-btn drop-menu btn1 sc-btn" href="#">item</a>

                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="onscroll" href="#">item</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a class="sub-btn drop-menu btn2 onscroll" href="#">item</a>

                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="onscroll" href="#">item</a></li>
       
 
            </ul>
    </div>

    </nav>


</header>
<section class="slider">


    <div class="slider-head">
        <h1 class="Be">R2</h1>
        <h1 class="center">Create <span>anything</span></h1>
        <h1 class="h-header center">you can imagine</h1>
        <div class="theme-version center">Version 1.0 not compleat yet</div>

    </div>

    <div class="slider-demos">

        <img src="assets/images/slider-demos-new.webp" alt="slider-demos">
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>sectionn</div>
</section>
```

I am trying to make a sticky header, and then scroll the header style change.
the header background changed but there was a problem with the ul link.

for now, all the ul a links have "onscroll" class, but there was no change.

a brief for the header HTML & CSS code below

```
const headerScroll = document.querySelector(".header");
const allMenuItem = document.querySelectorAll(".onscroll");


window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 0) {
        headerScroll.classList.add('head-change');
        allMenuItem.forEach(v => {
            v.classList.add('menu-change');
        });
    } else {
        headerScroll.classList.remove('head-change');
        v.classList.remove('menu-change');

    };

});
```

a brief for the header HTML & CSS code below.

Comment: Could you provide your HTML file as well, so I can test this locally?

Comment: You could try using the CSS selector ":hover" on your header element, and then use JavaScript to add a class to the header element when the user scrolls down the page.

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). On first glance, that looks fine, assuming the elements exist as of when that code runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is: your `v` is not defined in `else`, so you should use `for each` in `else` too.

The second problem is: your class `.menu-change` for some reason doesn't overwrite the default style, so just add `!important` to it in CSS.

one of the items in your nav is still white, I'll leave that to you to fix.

```js
//  sticty menu
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var header = document.querySelector("header");
    header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
});

// heder color
const headerScroll = document.querySelector(".header");
const allMenuItem = document.querySelectorAll(".onscroll");


window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 0) {
        headerScroll.classList.add('head-change');
        allMenuItem.forEach(v => {
            v.classList.add('menu-change');
        });
    } else {
        headerScroll.classList.remove('head-change');
        allMenuItem.forEach(v => {
            v.classList.remove('menu-change');
        });

    };

});
```

```css
.head-change {
  background-color: white;
}

.menu-change {
  color: black !important;
}

/* ==============   ================== */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header.sticky .navigation {
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transition-property: line-height;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
   transition: 0.6s;
}

.header:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.head-change {
  background-color: white;
}

.menu-change {
  color: black;
}

header .navigation {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 75px;
}

header .navigation .menu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}



.menu>li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.header:hover .menu>li a {
  color: var(--black);
}

.sub-menu>li a {
  color: var(--black);
  font-size: 1em;
}

.menu-item>a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 25px 0;
  margin: 18px;
  transform: 0.5s;
}

.menu-item>a:hover {
  color: #469dff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu .header-icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
}


.menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.sub-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -30px 5px -30px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}

.sub-item a {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

.sub-item:hover {
  background: #f4f6F7FF;
  ;
}

.sub-item:last-child:hover {
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}




.slider {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 13vh 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #343134;
  background-image: url(../assets/images/mr.webp);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.slider .slider-head {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 0;
}

.slider-head .Be {
  font-size: 7em;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: var(--main-color);
}

.slider-head:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 7em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.slider-head .h-header {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.slider-head .theme-version {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .35em .65em;
  font-size: .75em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
  <header id="head">
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#">logo</a>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <!-- menu-icon -->

            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a class="onscroll" href="#">item</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a class="sub-btn drop-menu btn1 sc-btn" href="#">item</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                  <a class="onscroll" href="#">item</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                  <a class="sub-btn drop-menu btn2 onscroll" href="#">item</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                  <a class="onscroll" href="#">item</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>

    </nav>


</header>
<section class="slider">


    <div class="slider-head">
        <h1 class="Be">R2</h1>
        <h1 class="center">Create <span>anything</span></h1>
        <h1 class="h-header center">you can imagine</h1>
        <div class="theme-version center">Version 1.0 not compleat yet</div>

    </div>

    <div class="slider-demos">

        <img src="assets/images/slider-demos-new.webp" alt="slider-demos">
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>sectionn</div>
</section>
```